# Error loading sound file from HTMLAudioElement in Safari from hosted server, but not localhost or Chrome

Tags: ionic-framework, audio, safari, html5-audio, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to add a click sound to my ionic5 app using `HTMLAudioElement`. It's loaded dynamically, but in the DOM it looks like this

```
<audio preload="auto" id="audio-player" controls="" src="assets/audio/448080__breviceps__wet-click.wav"></audio>
```

It works fine in Chrome in every environment, and it also works in Safari when hosted on `localhost:8100` with ionic dev server (see:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve)

But when I try to play the sound in Safari from firebase hosting `https://fishbowl-the-game.firebaseapp.com`, it fails with the following error:

```
this.audioPlayer.play().catch(
(err)=>{
   console.warn("audioPlayer, err=",err)
});
```

```
// error message from Safari 
[Warning] audioPlayer, err= – NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported. (common-es2015.js, line 1548)
Not SupportedError: The operation is not supported.
```

And when I go to load the `.wav` file directly, it works on Chrome, AND Safari over `localhost`,  but NOT Safari from `firebaseapp.com`

see: https://fishbowl-the-game.firebaseapp.com/assets/audio/448080__breviceps__wet-click.wav

```
// error message from Safari when loading the resource directly
[Error] Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load (448080__breviceps__wet-click.wav, line 0)
```

I know there are other posts on HTML5 audio issues with Safari, but my code works over `localhost` so I'm guessing it might be something else.

any ideas?

Comment: Use normal javascript audio class to play audio

Comment: if only you tossed me that flippant remark hours ago––it would have saved me so much time.  (I only say flippant because you should have named a package) But after a quick google, I `npm install howler --save` and all was good. many thanks.

Comment: No problem tour welcome mate <3.